# jQuery UI Theme not getting applied properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-theme

**UPDATE 2 - RESOLVED:**

Got it working: http://jsfiddle.net/7CvZ9/12/

Had to add some classes.

**UPDATE 1**

It is working a little better, because I have cleared up the resource management section of jsfiddle and only have the following resource now:

http://jsfiddle.net/7CvZ9/5/

This has fixed the dialog, but the sortables still don't seem to have a theme applied.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have setup 2 basic examples in the links below to show the problem.  For some reason, I can't seem to get the ui themes to work properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/7CvZ9/
and
http://jsfiddle.net/7CvZ9/1/

For example, the dialog theme is messed up, and the sortable theme is not showing at all.

Not sure what I have overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working: http://jsfiddle.net/7CvZ9/12/

Had to add some classes.

Answer (score 1):

There could be only few possible reasons you don't get the style applied.

1. Style reference is not correct
2. jQueryUI theme is not compatible with jQueryUI version
3. jQuery messes up with something else (another library)
4. You have custom styles which interfere with jQueryUI's theme.

And I think your problem is of type 4.

Comment: 1. the style references are in the manage resources section in the links I have provided.  2. Don't know how to check that from the links I have provided. 3. I am only using jquery libraries, 4, I do not have any custom themes.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this before and found it to be that I don't have all the appropriate CSS loaded for the widgets I'm using.  I tried this with jsfiddle and added to 'Manage Resources' the following url (and it worked):

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

I suspect this includes *all* the css for *all* the widgets.

When creating your custom download be sure to mark all the widgets since the generated css file will only contain the css for the selected widgets.

HTH

Comment: I've already got http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css in the resource management section of jsfiddle.

Comment: OK, but you could try the one I provided.  It worked for me.  The fact of the matter is that you do not have the full css included.

Comment: I have tried your link and it also fixes the dialog, but I don't see any theme applied to the sortable elements.

Comment: Probably not included --- the two files appear identical.  I have a sneaky suspicion there is a special character in the one not working that throws it off.  I have had this when merging css files myself.  Think it had to do with the BOM.

Comment: Do you have a link to a hosted css file which has all the themes for everything in jquery ui?

Comment: Actually I don't think the sortable widget has default css.  Not sure.